# I add a eventhandler to form's Load event ,it compiled with no error,but does not work as expect

Tags: c#

I want to add additional eventhandler to all forms in my project.
when each form `Load event` is fired,beside the code written in Form_Load(),
my eventhandler will  also be executed.

this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace eventHandlerIntercept {    
   static class Program    {
      /// <summary>
      /// The main entry point for the application.
      /// </summary>
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {

          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          //intercept all form's Load event
          Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
          foreach (Assembly a in assemblies)
          {
              Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
              foreach (Type t in types)
              {
                  if (t.IsPublic && t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
                  {
                      if (t.Namespace.Contains("eventHandlerIntercept"))    
                      {                        
                        EventInfo e1 = t.GetEvent("Load");

                        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("HandleCustomEvent");

                        Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(e1.EventHandlerType, mi);

                        object o1 = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                        e1.AddEventHandler(o1, handler);

                    }
                }
            }
         }
         Application.Run(new Form1());
    }


    public static void HandleCustomEvent(object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        // Do something useful here.
        MessageBox.Show("xyz");
    }
  }
 }
```

this code compile with no error ,but when Form1 display,it does not show a `message box` which content is `xyz`,where is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "intercept all form's Load event" by trying to do something with types. OnLoad event is instance event, so there is no way to add handler *before* instance of `Form`-derived object is created.

Your code actually creates instances of all From-derived classes and add listener, but you completely ignore resulting object and create one new for call to `Run`. To make that approach working you need to pass `o1` corresponding to `Form1` type to `Run` method.

You may want to write some sort of factory method that would create forms by type name and immediately attach your handler. And than you can use this method wherever you need to create new form (instead of calling constructor directly).

Comment: thanks for your reply,you mean add this line:Application.Run(o1);      after :e1.AddEventHandle(o1,handler);     is it right?   how to convert o1 from a object type to Form type?

Comment: @user2147152 `Application.Run((Form)o1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Form myForm = new Form();
myForm.Load += HandleCustomEvent;
Application.Run(myForm);
```

That worked for me, but the `MessageBox` is showed before the form itself, I don't know if that matters to you. Still, hope this helps, please feedback.

Comment: it also works for me,the question is,i want to add a eventhandler for all forms in my project, so i think,maybe there is a method can loop all forms and added eventhandler to them

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Every Form object is somewhere created, so you can add as much event handlers as you want to as much forms as you want in the way I just showed you. Maybe if you provide some code I could be more specific. Good luck!!!